# apex:detail not displaying

Tags: visualforce

Apex:detail is not displaying the details of Account in my developer edition. I tested it by changing Id of the url but still not displaying any account details.Anyone has same issue ?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:pageBlock title="Hello {!$User.FirstName}!">
    You are viewing the {!account.name} account.
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:detail/> 
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/) is not correct.I have added subject="{!Account.Id}" attribute to apex:detail tag and it displayed account details.

Below is the screen shot from [visuaforce developer guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL parameter is Case Sensitive, You might be Using 'ID' or 'Id'. Try changing to 'id' it will work.